# Check if the following series converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1 \cdot 4 \cdot 7 \cdot ... \cdot (3n+1)}{n^2 \cdot 3^n \cdot n!}$$

This is my solution:

Let's rewrite the question:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(3n+1)!!!}{n^2 \cdot 3^n \cdot n!}$$

If we use D'Alembert's criterion:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{(3n+4)(3n+1)!!!}{(n+1)^2\cdot3^n \cdot3 \cdot(n+1) \cdot n!}}{\frac{(3n+1)!!!}{n^2 \cdot 3^n \cdot n!}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3n^3 + 4n^2}{3n^3 + 9n^2 + 9n+3} = 1$$

Which doesn't give an answer. However, if we use Raabe's criterion:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n\cdot(1-\frac{3n^3 + 4n^2}{3n^3 + 9n^2 + 9n+3}) = \frac{5}{3}$$

I calculated the limit correctly, I get the same result from WolframAlpha. Since the result is greater than 1, the series **converge**.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: $\frac {1\cdot 4 \cdots}{n^2 3^n n!} < \frac {1}{n^2}$ so the series converges by the comparison test.

Comment: @DougM It seems to me that direct comparison test fails. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is fine, as an alternative by limit comparison test we have

$$\frac{\frac{(3n+1)!!!}{n^2 \cdot 3^n \cdot n!}}{\frac1{n^\frac 43}}=\frac{(3n+1)!!!}{n^\frac23 \cdot 3^n \cdot n!} \to 0$$

indeed by Stirling's approximation we have

$$\frac{(3n+1)!!!}{n^\frac23 \cdot 3^n \cdot n!}=\frac{(n+\frac13)!}{n^\frac23 \cdot n!} \sim \frac{\sqrt {2\pi (n+\frac13)}\cdot \left(\frac {(n+\frac13)} e\right)^{(n+\frac13)}}{n^\frac23 \cdot \sqrt {2\pi n}\cdot \left(\frac n e\right)^n}=$$
$$=\sqrt{1+\frac1{3n}}\cdot \frac{(n+\frac13)^\frac13}{ e^\frac13\cdot n^\frac23}\cdot \left(1+\frac1{3n}\right)^n \to 0$$

therefore the given series converges by [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with $\sum \frac1{n^\frac43}$.

Comment: I request one clarification please: Why does the first limit (that is, $\frac{\frac{1 \cdot 4 \cdot 7 \cdot ... \cdot (3n+1)}{n^2 \cdot 3^n \cdot n!}}{\frac1{n^2}}= \frac{1 \cdot 4 \cdot 7 \cdot ... \cdot (3n+1)}{ 3^n \cdot n!} $) tend to $1$? What follows after "indeed by ratio test" says nothing about that limit.

Comment: @Koro Which one? The limit I have indicated tends to zero.

Comment: I have modified my earlier comment to frame my doubt.

Comment: @Koro Ah you are referring to my previous answer which was indeed wrong. Ratio test is inconclusive and indeed $\frac{1 \cdot 4 \cdot 7 \cdot ... \cdot (3n+1)}{ 3^n \cdot n!} \to \infty$ as we can see using Stirling's approximation.

Comment: I see, I just refreshed this page. I also saw your revised answer and request only one clarification:  how is $\frac{(3n+1)!!!}{3^n}=(n+\frac13)!$? What confuses me is 1) RHS as it seems like gamma function in this; 2) I think that Stirling formula is used to approximate $n!$ and not things like $(n+\frac 23)!$ etc. Thanks.

Comment: @Koro We can extend factorial for integer via gamma function and then use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Stirling's_formula) for it.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that Stirling's approximation could also be used for extension of factorial to gamma function. Thank you so much :). +1

Comment: @Koro You are welcome! Bye